# Django with Jinja2: template search path

Tags: django, jinja2

I'm new to Jinja. Hope some one could answer this simple question.
If Jinja encounters the following at the line of the template:

```
{% extends "details.html" %}
```

what are the paths it will search to locate details.html? Is there a environment variable  or a variable in settings.py to set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should see something like this in your settings.py:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')    
        ],
        ...
    },
]
```

This assumes you have a folder named 'templates' where your templates live.

Django will search this folder for templates.